# How to get accessToeken in NextAuth?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am trying to implement a traditional authentication setup with **NextAuth**. The backend is sending a response like the below after a successful login. The library looks excellent but I don't see where the raw `accessToken` is saved or any way to get this. I need to add it with every request header I send to the backend. How to deal with this kind of authentication? I would be pleased if you spent some of your time helping me in this regard.

### Backend Response after login. FYI I can change the response if need

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "data": {
        "accesstoken": "eyJhbGcicCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImFzaWY.......",
        "user": {
            "name": "Participant",
            "image": "https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=4",
            "email": "asif.saho@gmail.com"
        }
    }
}
```

### This is what my `[...nextauth].ts` looks like.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import NextAuth, { Session, User } from 'next-auth';
import { JWT } from 'next-auth/jwt';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import { AUTH_CONST } from '../../../constants/authConst';
import { log } from '../../../services/logger';

const providers = [
  CredentialsProvider({
    type: 'credentials',
    id: 'credentials',
    name: 'credentials',
    credentials: {
      email: { label: 'email', type: 'email' },
      password: { label: 'password', type: 'password' },
    },
    authorize: async (_credentials, req) => {
      const res: Response = await axios.post(AUTH_CONST.signInBeUrl, {
        email: req.query!.email,
        password: req.query!.password,
      });

      if (res.data.statusCode === 200) {
        return res.data.data.user;
      }

      return null;
    },
  }),
];

const logger = {
  error(code: any, metadata: any) {
    log.error('next auth', JSON.stringify(code, null, 2));
    log.error('next auth', JSON.stringify(metadata, null, 2));
  },
  warn(code: any) {
    log.warn('next auth', JSON.stringify(code, null, 2));
  },
  debug(code: any, metadata: any) {
    log.info('next auth', JSON.stringify({ code, metadata }, null, 2));
  },
};

export default NextAuth({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  providers,
  debug: process.env.AUTH_DEBUG === 'true',
  logger,
  pages: {
    signIn: AUTH_CONST.signIn,
    signOut: AUTH_CONST.signOut,
    error: AUTH_CONST.error,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With NextAuth, you can use the session strategy as jwt. This is the default. The session is saved in a cookie and never persisted anywhere.

```js
session: {
  strategy: "jwt"
}
```

You can add an API handler that accepts the token and sets it to the cookie.

For example

```js
export default function handler(req, res) {
  const { token } = req.body;

  res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', `token=${token}`);
  res.json({});
}
```

The cookie is attached to all the requests sent to your backend.

```js
// This is an example of how to read a JSON Web Token from an API route
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt"

export default async (req, res) => {
  const token = await getToken({ req })

  if (token) {
    // Signed in
    console.log("JSON Web Token", JSON.stringify(token, null, 2))
  } else {
    // Not Signed in
    res.status(401)
  }
  res.end()
}
```

Example is taken from the NextAuth doc.

Comment: with the second snippet are you telling me to make an API route that will return the token?

Comment: In the second snippet, I showed you how to access JWT in the API route. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Perhaps for my less knowledge, I am 100% clear. Do I need to add the API handler in the Next JS? I think yes but what would the final file structure look like? Would you mind making implementation in a sandbox? I think many people are looking for this solution so It might be helpful to a lot of people.

I made a solution by intercepting Token from session callback and storing with user object but seems your solution is official.